# Scrape the Category of Products using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I am trying to scrape this page, it has around 21000 products

My question is how do i get all the products name,image and complete category hierarchy of 21000 products.
Image and name is on the same page but category is inside the actual product page.

because of pagination i am only able to get the 32 products title and image that is present on first page

**CODE for getting title from first page**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

main_url = "https://paytmmall.com/fmcg-foods-glpid-101405?discoverability=online&use_mw=1"

import requests
result = requests.get(main_url)
print(result.text)

sp = BeautifulSoup(result.text,'html.parser')
print(sp.prettify())

getallTitle = [x.a.get('title') for x in sp.findAll("div", class_ = "_3WhJ")]

print(str(len(getallTitle )) + " fetched products Title")
print("/n")
print(getallTitle[2])
```

Comment: Hi, I recommend Scrapy to crawl pages like this, BeautifulSoup doesn't provide easy ways to crawl next pages. Check out the [Scrapy Tutorial](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html).

Comment: @James Joyce, I can't see any category like fruits, can you specify which label you want to scrap in the product page.

Comment: But answering your actual question, if the information you want is not present on this page, you will have to collect the product URLs and download the page to get the category. Another way to do this, but it can generate false information in case of one product being in different category lists is get the URLs of all categories and then extract the products within them.

Comment: Both images and title is present on the main page i just have to work on pagination to get all products image and title, but category is not on same page .. if you click on any product inside that you will get a category of product `ex : https://paytmmall.com/red-label-tea-500-gm-CMPLXFASRED-LABEL-TEBIGB98583267DE367C-pdp?product_id=168390082&channel=WEB&discoverability=online&src=grid&svc=-1&tracker=%7C%7C%7C%7C%2Fg%2Ffmcg%2Ffoods-glpid-101405%7C101405%7C1%7C%7C%7C%7C&get_review_id=234061330` has a `Home/Supermarket/Foods/Drinks & Beverages/Tea & Coffee` category

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the json response of each page. But keep in mind, there are only 32 products per page which means you'll be requesting 659 times.

```
import requests
import math

url = 'https://middleware.paytmmall.com/fmcg-foods-glpid-101405'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36'}

payload = {
'channel': 'web',
'child_site_id': '6',
'site_id': '2',
'version': '2',
'discoverability': 'online',
'use_mw': '1',
'category': '101405',
'page': '1',
'page_count': '1',
'items_per_page': '32'}

# Get total pages needed
jsonData = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload).json()
total_count = jsonData['totalCount']
total_pages = total_count / 32
pages = math.ceil(total_pages)


# Iterate through each page
for page in range(1,pages + 1):
    payload.update({'page':page, 'page_count':page})

    jsonData = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload).json()

    for product in jsonData['grid_layout']:
        name = product['name']
        brand = product['brand']
        actual_price = product['actual_price']
        try:
            category = product['attributes']['type']
        except:
            category = 'N/A'

        print ('%-20s ₹%-5s %-20s ₹%s' %(category, actual_price, brand, name))
```

**Output:**

```
Tea                  ₹185   Red Label            Red Label Tea 500 gm
Tea                  ₹93    Tata Tea Premium     Tata Tea Premium Leaf 250 gm
Tea                  ₹240   Red Label            Red Label Natural Care Tea 500 gm
N/A                  ₹230   Taj Mahal            Taj Mahal Tea 500 gm
Tea                  ₹120   Red Label            Red Label Natural Care Tea 250 gm
Dairy Whitener       ₹413   Nestle               Nestle Everyday Dairy Whitener Milk 1 kg
Sauces               ₹125   Kissan               Kissan Fresh Tomato Ketchup 950 gm
Whole Oats           ₹186   Quaker               Quaker Oats 1 kg Pouch
Tea                  ₹188   Tata Tea Premium     Tata Tea Premium Leaf 500 gm
Coffee               ₹90    Bru                  BRU Instant Coffee 50 gm
Almond               ₹300   Freshco              Freshco California Almonds 200Gm
Jam                  ₹250   Kissan               Kissan Mixed Fruit Jam 1.04 kg
Almond               ₹799   glomin               Glomin California Almond Raw 500 G 1Pc
Sauces               ₹152   Kissan               Kissan Sweet & Spicy Sauce 1 kg
Cashew Nut           ₹180   Nutty Gritties       Nutty Gritties Roasted Salted Cashews 80G
Coffee               ₹120   Bru                  BRU Gold Instant Coffee 50 gm
Tea                  ₹480   Red Label            Red Label Natural Care Tea 1 kg
Almond               ₹310   Miltop               Miltop California Almonds 250G
Cashew Nut           ₹425   glomin               Glomin Cashew 250 G 1Pc
Almond               ₹600   Wonderland           Wonderland California Almond 500g
Almond               ₹499   Shivram Peshawari & Bros Shivram Peshawari & Bros California Almonds/Badam 250 Grams
Peanut Butter        ₹425   Pintola              Pintola All Natural Peanut Butter 1 kg (Crunchy)
Soups                ₹55    Knorr                Knorr Classic Tomato Soup 53 gm
Peanut Butter        ₹425   Pintola              Pintola All Natural Peanut Butter 1 kg (Creamy)
Peanut Butter        ₹349   Pintola              Pintola Classic Peanut Butter 1 kg (Crcuncy)
Peanut Butter        ₹165   Pintola              Pintola All Natural Peanut Butter 350 gm (Crunchy)
Almond               ₹1599  glomin               Glomin Raw Almonds 1Kg (Pack Of 1)
Almond               ₹150   Nutty Gritties       Nutty Gritties Almonds 100G
Raisin               ₹250   OOSH                 Oosh Seedless Black Raisin 250G
N/A                  ₹455   Taj Mahal            Taj Mahal Tea 1 kg
```

**Edit:**

If you want the hierarchy, you're going to need to go to each products' link and pull that out. I provided to code to do that, but keep in mind this will take FORVER. Assuming it takes about 2-3 seconds per request it will take you nearly 18 hours.

```
# Iterate through each page
for page in range(1,pages + 1):
    payload.update({'page':page, 'page_count':page})

    jsonData = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload).json()

    for product in jsonData['grid_layout']:
        name = product['name']
        brand = product['brand']
        actual_price = product['actual_price']
        img = product['image_url']
        category_id = product['category_id']

        new_url = product['newurl']

        jsonData_product = requests.get(new_url, headers=headers).json()

        category = '/'.join( [each['name'] for each in jsonData_product['ancestors'] ] )

        print ('Name: %s\nImage: %s\nCategory: %s\n' %(name, img, category))
```

**Output:**

```
Name: Red Label Tea 500 gm
Image: https://assetscdn1.paytm.com/images/catalog/product/F/FA/FASRED-LABEL-TETBL497475164B959/a_4.jpg
Category: Supermarket/Foods/Drinks & Beverages/Tea & Coffee/Red Label Tea 500 gm

Name: Tata Tea Premium Leaf 250 gm
Image: https://assetscdn1.paytm.com/images/catalog/product/F/FA/FASTATA-TEA-PREINNO985832A1E145F5/8.jpg
Category: Supermarket/Foods/Drinks & Beverages/Tea & Coffee/Tata Tea Premium Leaf 250 gm

Name: Red Label Natural Care Tea 500 gm
Image: https://assetscdn1.paytm.com/images/catalog/product/F/FA/FASRLNC-C-500GNTBL4974726639099/a_14.jpg
Category: Supermarket/Foods/Drinks & Beverages/Tea & Coffee/Red Label Tea & Coffee 500 Gm

Name: Taj Mahal Tea 500 gm
Image: https://assetscdn1.paytm.com/images/catalog/product/F/FA/FASTAJ-MAHAL-TEBIGB985832F0512392/0.jpg
Category: Supermarket/Foods/Drinks & Beverages/Tea & Coffee/Taj Mahal Tea 500 gm

Name: Red Label Natural Care Tea 250 gm
Image: https://assetscdn1.paytm.com/images/catalog/product/F/FA/FASNEW-RED-LABETBL49747FC4B364F/a_7.jpg
Category: Supermarket/Foods/Drinks & Beverages/Tea & Coffee/Red Label Natural Care Tea 250 gm

Name: Nestle Everyday Dairy Whitener Milk 1 kg
Image: https://assetscdn1.paytm.com/images/catalog/product/F/FA/FASNESTLE-EVERYTBL497478E1F2966/a_8.jpg
Category: Supermarket/Foods/Dairy Products/Dairy Whitener/Nestle Everyday Dairy Whitener Milk 1 kg
```

**OR**

If all the products are under the same categories, then you only really need to get the first product's categories, and then apply to all the others as you iterate through the pages:

```
import requests
import math

url = 'https://middleware.paytmmall.com/fmcg-foods-glpid-101405'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36'}

payload = {
'channel': 'web',
'child_site_id': '6',
'site_id': '2',
'version': '2',
'discoverability': 'online',
'use_mw': '1',
'category': '101405',
'page': '1',
'page_count': '1',
'items_per_page': '32'}

# Get total pages needed
jsonData = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload).json()
total_count = jsonData['totalCount']
total_pages = total_count / 32
pages = math.ceil(total_pages)


# Iterate through each page
category = ''
for page in range(1,pages + 1):
    payload.update({'page':page, 'page_count':page})

    jsonData = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload).json()

    for product in jsonData['grid_layout']:
        name = product['name']
        brand = product['brand']
        actual_price = product['actual_price']
        img = product['image_url']
        category_id = product['category_id']

        if category == '':
            new_url = product['newurl']
            jsonData_product = requests.get(new_url, headers=headers).json()
            category = '/'.join( [each['name'] for each in jsonData_product['ancestors'] ][:-1] )

        print ('Name: %s\nImage: %s\nCategory: %s\n' %(name, img, category))
```

Comment: The site is acting weirdly. The one you used `payload` within your post request should be used as `params` within get request to form a valid url but still it works whereas the right payload should be the one you can find in @QHarr's answer. If you try like this `requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload).json()`, it will still work. Strange!!!!

Comment: @SIM YES!. I noticed that as well. I originally had it as `params` parameter but not getting back what I was expecting. I simply changed it to data to see what would happend, and when I did, it worked, so I left it hat way. But you are correct, it's acting differently than what I was used to.

Comment: Thanks, but it is not giving me the desired category hierarchy like `Home/Supermarket/Foods/Drinks & Beverages/Tea & Coffee` ,you have used the category as `101405` so its giving the high level category, but i need complete hierarchy

Comment: @jamesjoyce thats all there, I provided it above. But are you really wanting to iterate through 21,000 products??

Comment: or I guess, are all the products going to be in the same hierarchy? If that's the case, just need to go to the first product, get that hierarchy, then you don't need to get it from the other product pages

Comment: Thanks...yes i need every product...no all the products are not in same hierarchy...i guess what i could do is go to the particular category hierarchy and get all the product of that hierarchy just because those products hierarchy will be same,but a manual work would increase coz there are almost 200 to 250 product in each hierarchy so for 21000 product its more than 100 hierarchy of category so any how this approach would consume time...so i think your second solution would work which is to  to go to each products' link and pull the category out..Thanks

Comment: I see. Well you have some options then. Just a matter of finding the optimal way of doing it

Answer (score 2):

The page makes a request for page one for content as follows (which returns json). See if you can alter parameters to get all results

It looks like you can alter the referer header and the current page in the body by altering the url to include page e.g.

```
https://paytmmall.com/fmcg-foods-glpid-101405?discoverability=online&use_mw=1&page=2
```

You can extract the total results count from your first request

```
r['filters'][0]['values'][0]['count']
```

You know you are requesting in batches of 32 (though try increasing this to the largest value possible). You can then calculate the number of pages/requests, then issue in a loop.

Python (page 1 request)

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
    'Referer' : 'https://paytmmall.com/fmcg-foods-glpid-101405?discoverability=online&use_mw=1',
    'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'
}

body = {"tracking":{"current_page":"https://paytmmall.com/fmcg-foods-glpid-101405?discoverability=online&use_mw=1","prev_page":''},"context":{"device":{"os":"Win32","device_type":"PC","browser_uuid":"GA1.2.105449259.1558439396","ua":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36","connection_type":"Unknown"},"channel":"WEB","user":{"ga_id":"GA1.2.105449259.1558439396","user_id":''}}}

r = requests.post('https://middleware.paytmmall.com/fmcg-foods-glpid-101405?channel=web&child_site_id=6&site_id=2&version=2&discoverability=online&use_mw=1&items_per_page=32', json = body, headers = headers).json()
```

Comment: Exactly. In addition, your results are stored in the following key r['grid_layout']. For 20 000 products,   in would loop ~700 times to get all results.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to tackle pagination. 
Pagination is nothing but it just send request on demand instead of fetching it at once. It means every times you click on any page number you will see some change according to the websites design. 
In your case url query is changing every time you click on any pagelink. The produced url is

```
https://paytmmall.com/fmcg-foods-glpid-101405?discoverability=online&use_mw=1&category=101405&page=2
```

If you will keep changing the page=2 to whatever page you want to scrape you will be able to scrape the website.

> Logic:

```
main_url = "https://paytmmall.com/fmcg-foods-glpid-101405? discoverability=online&use_mw=1&category=101405&page="

for i in range(1,totalnumberofpages):
 url = main_url+str(i)
 #you logic to scrape one url
```